# Chakra-UI pro theme css does not apply

Tags: reactjs, vite, chakra-ui

I am following [this documentation](https://pro.chakra-ui.com/guides/get-started) with the simple `Vite` starter in [here](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/vite-guide). My setup is pretty simple:

**main.tsx**

```js
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { theme } from "@chakra-ui/pro-theme";
import "@fontsource/inter/variable.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const App = () => {
  return <Button>Button</Button>;
};

export default App;
```

However, styles are not applied to the button. What am I doing wrong?